# Locked appointment on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar

I have a locked appointment on my iPad that doesn't appear on the laptop or iPhone. I can't delete it either... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a **calendar appointment provided by a subscribed calendar**. Either hide or remove the calendar to remove the appointment.